# How to measure active user for "click event" in real time google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've added a "click event" on google analytics, when someone click, a popup window shows. On "real time > event" it shows increment on active user. Now I need to know if user close that popup then the active user will decrements ? Basically I want to know how they measure active user ?
[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the moment there is activity a user is counted as active.

For example if the only thing you measure on your page is a certain event and **NO** pageviews, then the user will only show active from the moment the event is triggered.

That said, a user will be inactive when he has not performed any measured actions (pageviews/events/..) on your website for a specific amount of time , which can be configured in your admin section.

Comment: Say if someone clicked on a button a user agreement article will be opened, and I'm measuring the click event through button. So if user click the button then he will be counted as active user then if user close the agreement article, does he counted as inactive user ? Or he needs to be inactive for a certain period to be counted as inactive user?

Comment: Indeed if he clicks he's active , if he does nothing for a certain period he will be inactive